# Как посчитать количество столбцов в матрице Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо подсчитать количество столбцов, не значения столбцов, а именно количество столбцов

пример часть кода, после фильтров, из таблицы делаем матрицу.

```
matrix = pd.pivot_table (table, index="Period", columns="ID", fill_value=0)

matrix1 = matrix.groupby(np.arange(len(matrix))//5).sum()

quantity_ID = matrix_final["ID"].size()


print(quantity_ID)
```

[image: Матрица примерно такого вида]

В строчке quantity_ID = matrix_final["ID"].size() пытаюсь получить кол-во ID которые идут по столбцам, но выдает ошибку.
Нужно именно на выходе получить запись вида quantity_ID = 350 к примеру, для того чтобы потом использовать переменную quantity_ID в дальнейшем коде, чтобы не считать это количество вручную. всегда, ибо количество ID всегда разное.

Comment: `matrix_final.shape[1]` ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объектов Pandas и Numpy есть атрибут [.shape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html), показывающий размерность матрицы/таблицы.

Пример:

```
In [57]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 20))

In [58]: df.shape
Out[58]: (12, 20)

In [59]: df.shape[1]
Out[59]: 20            #  <--- число столбцов
```